# itunesConnect not showing all development teams

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-developer

I have 4 development teams in itunes connect developer account. Every time I log in to itunesconnect it logs me in to one team and I can't find a way to switch to the 4th team. It is showing only 3 teams. Can't we have more than 3 teams in apple developer?

Comment: What is your role in the apple developer account ?

Comment: @byJeevan my Role is Admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue Resolved!
I would like to share the solution here.

I was an admin user in that team but not an itunes connect user. For this Team agent should send an invitation to the user to join in itunesConnect Users.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

A valid apple id is required to be connected by sending invitation to join as itunesConnect Users.